# Webforms - Upload Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, progress-bar

I am looking to create a file upload progress bar for my webforms, I have read a few ways to do this yet all of those ways require server side scritps. I use a hosted CMS and do not have access to server side scripts. Is there a way to fake a progress bar using jQuery? I want it to be represented as realistic as possible. Meaning when I upload a large file it will show progress but not finish before the file finishes uploading. How can I achieve this?

Note: Solution must work in IE8+, FF, Chrome, Safari and preferably Android and iOS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find out the current progress of an upload using JavaScript alone. If you don't have access to the server, you should consider alternative methods, such as Flash.

Comment: I have looked at flash methods yet they all require some form of server side. Is there one that does not?

Comment: @Lynda, Flash doesn't require any special treatment from the server. You can upload a file like you normally would, but Flash gives you the ability to monitor the upload, something that is not available in JavaScript. Also, note that Flash is not supported on iOS.